# Dismissing Alert View of controller or app whose object refference is not available..!

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad

How to dismiss the alert view (and execute its cancellation handler) when my
application moves back to the foreground or my refference object is not
available?
If any one knows please reply.
Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way. You need to keep a reference and subscribe to the [`UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification) notifications. When you get that message you can call the [`dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006802-CH3-SW18) which, as the documentation says, "in iPhone OS 4.0, you may want to call this method whenever your application moves to the background."